# python for a in b, a not in b

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of datetime objects.  The idea is that I have to use the unique dates inside a for loop to do things.  Something is stumping me.  The problem is illustrated below.  I do a for loop, `for d in np.unique(dates):`.  But then inside the for loop I would expect `d in np.unique(dates)` and also `d in dates` to return `True`, but it returns false every time?

I use this as an illustration of the problem.

```
import numpy as np    

....
print type(dates[0])
print dates[0]
print 'start for loop -----'
for d in np.unique(dates):
    print type(d)
    print 'd: ',d
    print 'd in np.unique(dates): ',d in np.unique(dates)
    print 'd in dates',d in dates
```

OUTPUT:

```
<type 'numpy.datetime64'>
2010-05-22T02:00:00.000000000+0200
start for loop -----
<type 'numpy.datetime64'>
d:  2010-05-22T02:00:00.000000000+0200
d in np.unique(dates):  False
d in dates:  False
<type 'numpy.datetime64'>
d:  2010-07-17T02:00:00.000000000+0200
d in np.unique(dates):  False
d in dates:  False
....
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

>>> x = np.datetime64('2010-05-22T02:00:00.000000000+0200')
>>> x in [x]
True
>>> x in np.unique([x])
True
>>> for a in np.unique([x]):
...   print a in np.unique([x])
... 
True

Comment: Agreed ^. How are you populating `dates`? How are you adding `d` to `dates`?

Comment: me too , I also got `True` by the dates as `dates=[np.datetime64('2005-02-25')]`, which version of the numpy lib do you use?

Comment: Dunno whether it's related to the problem, but NumPy's `in` is pretty weird. `x in arr` is exactly equivalent to `(arr == x).any()`, so you get weirdness like `array([1, 2]) in array([1])` or `array([1, 2]) in array([1, 3])`.

Comment: Well the array comes from one column of a larger matrix array that is loaded from a .npy file.  I just tried using `dates = np.array([np.datetime64('2010-05-22T02:00:00.000000000+0200')])`, and i got True and True...

Comment: I hate asking this, but, maybe it's your hardware, so... Have you tried turning it off and on again? I've seen some funky python logic failures on old Mac Server machines that were solved by rebooting. Total ghost in the shell.

Comment: I'm glad you said that.  I was able to get around the problem by executing this line at the ver top: `dates = list(dates)` to convert the array to a normal list, and it worked.  But I will revert back, reboot and try it just to check.  I am using a late 2013 macbook with anaconda.

Comment: Still the same after the reboot.  Must be something with the data...

Answer (score 1):

As the others i am not able to reproduce the error. Here is my implementation of your code that forked absolutely fine. I am using Ubuntu 15.04 with python 3.5 and numpy 1.10.1

As the others i am not able to reproduce the error. But maybe it helps here is my implementation of your code. If you provide more info about your system -- maybe it helps. I am using Ubuntu 15.04

import numpy as np 
    import sys
    import platform
    print("Arch:", platform.architecture())
    print("Python version:",".".join([str(v) for v in sys.version_info[0:3]]))
    print("numpy version:",np.**version**)
    Arch: ('64bit', 'ELF')
    Python version: 3.5.0
    numpy version: 1.10.1

```
dates = np.arange('2015-02', '2015-03', dtype='datetime64[D]')
print(dates)
#prints
['2015-02-01' '2015-02-02' '2015-02-03' '2015-02-04' '2015-02-05'
 '2015-02-06' '2015-02-07' '2015-02-08' '2015-02-09' '2015-02-10'
 '2015-02-11' '2015-02-12' '2015-02-13' '2015-02-14' '2015-02-15'
 '2015-02-16' '2015-02-17' '2015-02-18' '2015-02-19' '2015-02-20'
 '2015-02-21' '2015-02-22' '2015-02-23' '2015-02-24' '2015-02-25'
 '2015-02-26' '2015-02-27' '2015-02-28']

print(type(dates[0]))
print(dates[0])
print('start for loop -----')
for d in np.unique(dates):
    print (type(d))
    print ('d: ',d)
    print ('d in np.unique(dates): ',d in np.unique(dates))
    print ('d in dates',d in dates)

#prints 
<class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2015-02-01
start for loop -----
<class 'numpy.datetime64'>
d:  2015-02-01
d in np.unique(dates):  True
d in dates True
```

...

Comment: thanks for the effort.  I can explicitly define the dates variable on my system and it works fine.  For some reason when I get the dates from the save numpy file it fails.  Like I said I got around it by doing `dates = list(dates)`.  You would think the numpy array would work the same way as the regular list, but it doesn't in this case.  Its a very strange error.